# Vi Showing Extra Characters ( *>> ) where spaces should be

Tags: vim, text-editor

I've been using vim from the past few months and am trying to make it my go-to text editor for all text files.

I recently downloaded the most recent version of WordPress and noticed that all the files display a character sequence( »·»·»·»·) where a space is expected.

How can I change this to show spaces instead?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's highlighting tab characters, not spaces. Turn it off with `:set nolist`. You can also see what hidden characters are configured to show with `:set listchars?`